# Jquery auto complete not displaying the list

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, autocomplete

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("GetReports")'
});
```

This is what I have in my JQuery which calls the method `GetReports`. The method in the controller is returning the correct data and I'm only return first       `return Json(filteredReports.Take(2), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

When I type something in the text box, the list doesn't appear however, when I press up and down arrow, I can see the text is appearing in box correctly.

I have tried putting

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

in my CSS file but no luck. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a CSS issue. I have this:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: default;
color: #555;
font-size: 14px;
}

.ui-menu {
list-style:none;
padding: 2px;
margin: 0;
display:block;
float: left;
```

}

```
.ui-menu .ui-state-focus,
.ui-menu .ui-state-active {
margin: -1px;
}


.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
padding: 3px 1em 3px .4em;
cursor: pointer;
 }
```